# Excel ODBC DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

Trying to access an Excel file as database using ODBC driver. and need to determine the date difference in days and check the duration as following :

```
select A.IdNumber,A.UserNumber,A.StartDate,A.EndDate,B.StartDate,B.EndDate,A.TicketAmount,B.TicketAmount,A.Type,A.FromCity,A.ToCity,B.FromCity,B.ToCity 
from [Sheet1$] A, [Sheet1$] B    
where A.UserNumber = B.UserNumber 
and A.Type LIKE '%نتداب%' and B.Type LIKE '%نتداب%' 
and A.FromCity = B.FromCity and A.ToCity = B.ToCity 
and A.TicketAmount <> 0  and B.TicketAmount <> 0 
and ((DATEDIFF(day,B.StartDate,A.EndDate) = 1) or (DATEDIFF(day,B.StartDate,A.EndDate) = 0))
```

Error Occurred is :
Run query: ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

it is works fine without last line:

```
and ((DATEDIFF(day,B.StartDate,A.EndDate) = 1) or (DATEDIFF(day,B.StartDate,A.EndDate) = 0))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you building this query - SSMS?

Comment: `JOIN` Is the standard for joining tables for 30-odd years, comma separated joins are harder to write (correctly), read and change (to an outer join, for example). `'%نتداب%'` Is a unicode value, it should be `N'%نتداب%'`

Comment: i know about join tables but it is a task by perform same join behavior without using join keyword that's all, also it is not my problem at all .. thanks